# Jenkins job fails for python3 targets

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, makefile, jenkins-pipeline

I've been trying to run a Jenkins job(for python3 label) but it fails on the `linting` and `testing` stage. Here are the details on each stage :

**linting :**  This stage triggers the Makefile target `make lint` that tries to run pylint on all the python files in my project.
i.e. `pylint $(shell find -type f -name "*.py")`

**testing :**  This stage triggers the Makefile target `make test` that tries to run pytest on all the files in my project.
i.e. `pytest --cov=. --cov-report=term --cov-report=html --cov-fail-under=95 my_project`

Both the above stages require some pre-installation or virtualenv setup in Jenkins for it to recognize the commands `pylint` and `pytest`.

I tried setting it up by specifying the virtualenv path and then running the `pip install` for all required packages as follows :

**Jenkinsfile :**

```
    stage("linting") {
      steps {
        withEnv(["HOME=${env.WORKSPACE}", "PATH+PIP=${env.WORKSPACE}/.local/bin"]) {
          sh "make lint-code"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Makefile:**

```
lint-code: 
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    @pylint $(shell find -type f -name "*.py")
```

**requiremnts.txt**

```
pylint
pytest
```

I'm getting `make: pylint: Command not found Makefile:5: recipe for target 'lint' failed` or `make: pylint: Command not found Makefile:5: Error [127]`

Also, the $PATH did not setup even after passing it on the Jenkins stage and hence gives the following error :

`The scripts py.test and pytest are installed in '/home/ubuntu/workspace/my_project_PR-56/.local/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Comment: You should not use make's `$(shell ...)` function in a recipe.  Your recipe is _already_ running in the shell, there's no need for it and it can cause confusing behavior because it's expanded first, before the rest of the recipe.  Use shell syntax instead, like `$$(find -type f -name "*.py")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your PATH variable in Jenkins where pytest or scripts are kept.
Another option could be to use `dir` with the path where your scripts are present :

```
// dir("<Your path where scripts are present>")
dir ("/home//ubuntu/workspace//my_project_PR-56//.local//bin"){
     sh "make lint-code"
 }
```

**EDIT**:

You can also use variables inside using `env` or via `params`as: `dir(<YOURVARIABLE_Containing_the PATH>)`

```
pipeline 
{
parameters
    {
        string(name: 'Script_Location', defaultValue: '/home//ubuntu/workspace//my_project_PR-56//.local//bin', description: 'Where the script shall be executed')
}
stage ('stage 1'){
dir (params.Script_Location){
     sh "make lint-code"
  }
}
}
```

OR

```
dir ($WORKSPACE)
```

Comment: Thanks @Altaf. That works. But, in the above path the PR number will change every time there's a new pull request in the repository.
Is there a way we can get this path from Jenkins environment and pass it on to the `dir` ?

Comment: @AnchalVerma if this works for you then request you to accept the answer. In ``dir`` Yes that is possible, either you can use environment variable. Eg: ``dir (env.<YOURVARIABLE>)`` or passing as a parameter ``dir(params.<YOURVARIABLE>)``, I have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you Altaf, that worked. I had to just replace it with `($WORKSPACE)`

Comment: @Anchal Verma cool!Can you accept the answer if it helped you. I have updated it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Update your makefile for lint-code as below:

**Makefile**

```
lint-code: 
    pip install --upgrade pip
    python3 -m venv venv
    source ./venv/bin/activate
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    deactivate
    source ./venv/bin/activate
    @pylint $(shell find -type f -name "*.py")
```

Comment: I tried this but it was not able to set `venv` and had thrown the error saying virtualenv not found. I also tried installing it but that did not work as well.

Anyways, I was able to make it work by adding `dir` to locate to current directory as suggested by @Altaf